gradle gives an error in sqflite_android and java
when i try to build a app it gives me this error:
`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.`

i already have the last version of java, of gradle and of the sqflite.
I already also run flutter doctor and its all ok.
i do flutter clean and run again
i do some research but none of the solutions work for me
Can you help me please?
thanks in advance
i already have the last version of java, of gradle and of the sqflite.
I already also run flutter doctor and its all ok.
i do flutter clean and run again
i do some research but none of the solutions work for me
I already creat a new app of counter and it works fine

It may be a mismatch or configuration issue with your gradle version and your Android SDK. I recommend to open the "android" folder of your Flutter project with Android Studio IDE and let the IDE to build the gradle. If there is a conflict, it will show you the exact issue in the build message section.

it is solved. you can close.
the isue is about java and defining the way
flutter config --jdk-dir  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/home
and put you definition

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
